# How to access delphi open array parameter in inline assembly

Tags: delphi, assembly, delphi-7, inline-assembly, calling-convention

Suppose I have a delphi function like this:

```
procedure sortArray(arr: array of DWORD); register;
asm
  //access array here
end;
```

How would I access a specific element of the array in inline-assembly? I already know that arr actually consists of 2 parameters: a pointer to the array and its High(), but I need to know exactly how it works. I assume the pointer will be in eax and the High-value in ebx, but I'm not quite sure.

```
procedure sortArray(arr: array of DWORD); register;
asm
  mov DWORD PTR [eax+$4], $09 //set the second element of arr to 9 ???
end;
```

btw. if anyone wonders: I'm doing this in assembly because

a) I want to enhance my asm-skills

b) I have to do this for school and want to make it a little less boring

Comment: You can determine this by yourself when you'll be working with the CPU debug window.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of trial and error learning. Reading the documentation should be the first step. Why resort to reverse engineering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing to do is to stop passing arrays by value. For large arrays this will be inefficient. Instead of pass by value, declare the parameter to be `const`.

However, since your function is named `sortArray`, and since your code attempts to modify the array, it would appear more likely that you need a `var` parameter to get the desired semantics.

```
procedure sortArray(var arr: array of DWORD);
```

The ABI for open arrays is documented in the [Program Control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control) topic of the language guide. It states that:

> An open-array parameter is passed as two 32-bit values. The first value is a pointer to the array data, and the second value is one less than the number of elements in the array.

So, your function is effectively the same as:

```
procedure sortArray(ArrPtr: PDWORD; ArrHigh: Integer);
```

From there, you merely need to understand the calling convention, again documented in the [Program Control](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Program_Control) topic of the language guide:

> The first three parameters that qualify are passed in the EAX, EDX, and ECX registers, in that order.

So, `ArrPtr` is passed in `EAX`, and `ArrHigh` is passed in `EDX`.

Comment: thanks, but are you sure that ArrHigh is actually a delphi Integer? Since the number of elements can never be negative, I think it would rather be an unsigned 32bit int, thus a DWORD/CARDINAL. The documentation doesn't say whether it's signed or not.

Also could you tell my if this line is right?
    
    `mov DWORD PTR [eax+$4], $09 //set the second element of arr to 9 ???`

Comment: @Cody227 The number of elements can never be negative. That is true. But `ArrHigh` is not the number of elements. It is the index of the last element. So, `High(arr) = Length(arr)-1`. And when there are no elements, `HighArr` is -1. So yes, the second parameter is signed.

Comment: Yes, `mov DWORD PTR [eax+$4], $09` will assign `$9` to the second element. Of course, you'd need to check that there actually was a second element in real code.

Comment: Of course, one needs to realize that `array of X`, if found in a parameter list, can only be an *open array parameter*. I wrote an atricle about this (shamelessly plugging): [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).